# Docusign Api - Document does not change when using composite template

Tags: php, docusignapi

Using the php SDK I am using composite templates and when I try to update the document the document does not change. All I receive is the same document used for the server template. Looked through all documentation and other similar questions online but not sure what to do next.

Here is the code:

```
private function make_envelope(array $args): EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        // create roles for signers
        $signer = new Signer([

            'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
            'role_name' => "signer", 'recipient_id' => "1",
        ]);

        # Create the company signer recipient
        $companySigner = new Signer([

            'email' => $args['companySigner_email'], 'name' => $args['companySigner_name'],
            'role_name' => "companySigner", 'recipient_id' => "2"

        ]);

        # Recipients object:
        $recipients_server_template = new Recipients([
            'signers' => [$signer, $companySigner]
        ]);


        //code this to show the link to the built contract url/location
        $doc_file = './properties/55/generalDocument/file.pdf';
        $content_bytes = file_get_contents($doc_file);
        $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);

        # Create the document model
        $documentUpdated = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
            'name' => 'To be signed: Prepared Customer Agreement',  # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);

        # Create a composite template
        $comp_template1 = new CompositeTemplate([
            'composite_template_id' => "1",
            'document' => $documentUpdated,
            'server_templates' => [
                new ServerTemplate([
                    'sequence' => "1", 'template_id' => $args['template_id']
                ])
            ],
            # Add the roles via an inlineTemplate
            'inline_templates' => [
                new InlineTemplate([
                    'sequence' => "1",
                    'recipients' => $recipients_server_template
                ])
            ]
        ]);

        # Create the envelope definition with the composited templates
        $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([

            'status' => "sent",

            'composite_templates' => [$comp_template1]

        ]);

        return $envelope_definition;
    }
```

#################################################################

```
private function make_template_req(): EnvelopeTemplate
    {
        # document 1 is a pdf
        #
        # The template has two recipient roles.
        # recipient 1 - customer
        # recipient 2 - company
        # Read the pdf from the built customer contract
        # The reads could raise an exception if the file is not available!

        //code this to show the link to the built contract url/location
        $doc_file = '20210111-1417_ServiceAgreement.pdf';
        $content_bytes = file_get_contents(self::DEMO_DOCS_PATH . $doc_file);
        $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);



        # Create the document model
        $document = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
            'name' => 'Does built PDF work - Customer Agreement',  # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc

        ]);


        # Create the signer recipient model
        # Since these are role definitions, no name/email:
        $signer = new Signer([
            'role_name' => 'signer', 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"
        ]);
        # create a company signer recipient model
        $companySigner = new Signer([
            'role_name' => 'companySigner', 'recipient_id' => "3", 'routing_order' => "3"
        ]);


        # Create tab fields using absolute positioning (note that you must deduct 21 points from adobe y coordinate to match docusign)
        $sign_here1 = new SignHere([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "3",
            'x_position' => "40", 'y_position' => "409"
        ]);
        $sign_here2 = new SignHere([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "3",
            'x_position' => "40", 'y_position' => "500"
        ]);
        $sign_here3 = new SignHere([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "4",
            'x_position' => "60", 'y_position' => "454"
        ]);
        $sign_here5 = new SignHere([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "4",
            'x_position' => "60", 'y_position' => "567"
        ]);
        // $sign_here6 = new SignHere([
        //     'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "4",
        //     'x_position' => "60", 'y_position' => "454"
        // ]);
        $initial_here1 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '349'
        ]);
        $initial_here2 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '401'
        ]);
        $initial_here3 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '600'
        ]);
        $initial_here4 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '655'
        ]);
        $initial_here5 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '53'
        ]);
        $initial_here6 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '100'
        ]);
        $initial_here7 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '164'
        ]);
        $initial_here8 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '219'
        ]);
        $initial_here9 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '285'
        ]);
        $initial_here10 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '325'
        ]);
        $initial_here11 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '380'
        ]);
        $initial_here12 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '421'
        ]);
        $initial_here13 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '480'
        ]);
        $initial_here14 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '553'
        ]);
        $initial_here15 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '600'
        ]);
        $initial_here16 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '633'
        ]);
        $initial_here17 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '3',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '207'
        ]);
        $initial_here18 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '3',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '251'
        ]);
        $initial_here19 = new InitialHere([
            'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '3',
            'x_position' => '154', 'y_position' => '306'
        ]);
        $full_name1 = new FullName([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "3",
            'x_position' => "211", 'y_position' => "410",
            'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size12", 'tab_label' => "text",
            'height' => "23", 'width' => "90", 'required' => "true"
        ]);
        $date_signed1 = new DateSigned([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "5",
            'x_position' => "132", 'y_position' => "520",
            'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size12", 'tab_label' => "DateSigned",
            'height' => "23", 'width' => "84", 'required' => "true"
        ]);
        $date_signed2 = new DateSigned([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "6",
            'x_position' => "132", 'y_position' => "477",
            'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size12", 'tab_label' => "DateSigned",
            'height' => "23", 'width' => "84", 'required' => "true"
        ]);




        # Add the tabs model to the customer signer
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer->setTabs(new Tabs([
            'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here1, $sign_here3],
            'full_name_tabs' => [$full_name1],
            'initial_here_tabs' => [$initial_here1, $initial_here2, $initial_here3, $initial_here4, $initial_here5, $initial_here6, $initial_here7, $initial_here8, $initial_here9, $initial_here10, $initial_here11, $initial_here12, $initial_here13, $initial_here14, $initial_here15, $initial_here16, $initial_here17, $initial_here18, $initial_here19],
            'date_signed_tabs' => [$date_signed1, $date_signed2]
        ]));

        # Add the tabs model to the company signer
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $companySigner->setTabs(new Tabs([
            'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here2, $sign_here5]
        ]));

        # Template object:
        $template_request = new EnvelopeTemplate([
            'description' => "TEST Customer Agreement Template",
            'name' => $this->template_name,
            'shared' => "false",
            'documents' => [$document], 'email_subject' => "Please sign your Customer Agreement to secure your service",
            'recipients' => new Recipients([
                'signers' => [$signer, $companySigner]
            ]),
            'status' => "created"
        ]);

        return $template_request;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're using sequence = 1 for both inline and serverTemplates. That would lead to undefined behavior.

The inlineTemplate should get a sequence number of 2.

Comment: Envelope sends after the sequence change but the document is still the server template document. I found this information from https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates: "Consider leaving out the base64 encoding of documents. Composites provide an additional element (
compositeTemplateId
) to make it easy to use multipart form requests and pass the documents in their native binary format". How would I do this?

Comment: no luck with your answer @Nima. Any other help?

Comment: Can you provide some information about your server template? Can you paste its definition here? Does it only include roles and where the tabs are located for each?

Comment: If so, let's use this Json and hit it against our endpoint and see what result you get:

Comment: "compositeTemplates": [
    {
       "compositeTemplateId": "1",
       "document": {
            "documentId": "1",
             "name": "Anchor",
            "documentBase64": "JVBER...."
        },
       "inlineTemplates": [
        {
           "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                 "email": ".",
                  "name": ".",
                   "recipientId": "1",
                      "roleName": "."}]},
               "sequence": "2"}],
        "serverTemplates": [{
          "sequence": "1",
           "templateId": "." }] }

Comment: Or you can use the json above and hit the endpoint: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/accountId/envelopes and see what you get.

Comment: Hi @Nima, I have added the server template definition in the code above for you to review, yes it includes roles and tab locations.

Comment: I am using the PHP SDK through my SSH server and am not familiar with how to use json to do the above.

Comment: read through the docusign blog on using postman @Nima in order to try to test out the json with the endpoint you mentioned - I am having trouble with the authentication and when I send the request I receive 401 error code - AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN, I don't quite understand the OATH directions and tried to enter a bearer token using my integration key.

Comment: You can follow the instructions on step3 from https://docusign.github.io/postman-collections/ to get your token

Comment: Tried that and it returned INVALID OAUTH STATE in the browser.